# SQL query to group by or having?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table A which has a column BMI and I want to find out how many of them are within the range and i have 4 ranges.

I want to have the result of something like that, how can I do the sql query??

```
<18.5     ,10
18.5–24.9 ,25
25–29.9   ,19
>30       ,2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select case
         when bmi < 18.5 then
          '<18.5'
         when bmi > 18.5 and < 24.9 then
          '18.5–24.9'
         when bmi < 25 and > 29.9 then
          '25–29.9'
         when bmi > 30 then
          '>30'
       end as bmi_rg,
       count(*) as num_bmis
  from your_table
 group by case
            when bmi < 18.5 then
             '<18.5'
            when bmi > 18.5 and < 24.9 then
             '18.5–24.9'
            when bmi < 25 and > 29.9 then
             '25–29.9'
            when bmi > 30 then
             '>30'
          end
```

Use a CASE statement. To show the count per group, you also have to GROUP BY that case statement.

Comment: got voted down for saying the exact same thing. But this should work.

Comment: @programnub112 . . . Your query was incorrect (compare the `group by` cluases).  As a note:  I didn't downvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a union query for each of the specified ranges

```
select count(*) from table where bmi < 18.5
union select count(*) from table where bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 25
union select count(*) from table where bmi >=25 and bmi < 30
union select count(*) from table where bmi > 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select case when bmi < 18.5 then '<18.5'
            when bmi betwen 18.5 and 24.9 then '18.5–24.9'
            when bmi betwen 25 and 29.9 then '25–29.9'
            when bmi > 30 then '>30'
       end as bmi_group,
       count(*) as grp_count
from your_table
group by case when bmi < 18.5 then '<18.5'
              when bmi betwen 18.5 and 24.9 then '18.5–24.9'
              when bmi betwen 25 and 29.9 then '25–29.9'
              when bmi > 30 then '>30'
         end
```

The trick is that when the same CASE statement is used in group by, you achieve the grouping based on the "range of BMIs" rather than the actual BMI value itself. Same can be achieved using Oracle [Analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174), take a look at that option as well.